# How to prove that the following estimators are biased and consistent?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

Given a random variable $X$ following a geometric distribution with parameter $p.$ Then one estimator that can be obtained by considering the second moment $E[X^{2}]=\frac{2-p}{p^2}$, which is 
$$\hat{p}_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+\frac{8}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}}{\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}.$$
Another family of estimators can be obtained by observing that $E[\mathbf{1}_{[k,\infty)}X_1] = P[X_1>k]=(1-p)^{k}$ and so 
$$\hat{p}_2 = 1- \frac{\log\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{[k,+\infty)}(X_i)\right)}{k}.$$
I want to determine whether $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$ are biased and consistent, but this seems difficult since I am not able to figure the distribution of these estimators. Perhaps I have to use inequalities, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints will be much appreciated.

**Edit**: 
Let $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2/n$ then
$$E[\hat{p}_1]=E[f(Y)]$$
where 
$$f(y) = \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8y}}{2y}$$
then since $f''(y)>0$ using the Jensen Inequality we have that:
$$E[f(Y)]>f(E[Y])\implies E[\hat{p}_1]>p.$$
For the second estimator, we try Jensen with $Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{[k,+\infty)}(X_i)$ and $$f(y)=1-\frac{\log(y)}{k}.$$Then $$f''(y)=-\frac{1}{yk}<0$$ and so we have that 
$$E[\hat{p}_2]=E[f(Y)]<f(E[Y])=p.$$
I think this argument shows that $\hat{p}_1$ and $\hat{p}_2$ are biased. I am not very sure as to how the law of large numbers will work with the random variable $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2/n$ since it is not exactly an average. Perhaps someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Both are consistent by the law of large numbers. The second one is biased by Jensen inequality. Probably the first one as well, also by convexity...

Comment: Hmmm... All these arguments were already mentioned to you à propos [your previous recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050561/). Why are you not trying to apply them in the present context?

Comment: Hey, I made some edits. I hope my question makes more sense now.

Comment: 1. In the log case, your $f''$ is wrong. 2. The random variable $Y=\frac1n\sum X_k^2$ **is exactly** an average hence the LLN applies perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For the first estimator we can use the strong law of large numbers to deduce that since $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ are i.i.d, it follows that $\sum_1^n X_i/n\stackrel{\text{a.s}}{\to} EX=1/p$ whence
$$
\hat{p}=\frac{1}{\sum_1^n X_i/n}\stackrel{\text{a.s}}{\to} \frac{1}{1/p}=p
$$
as $n\to \infty$. So the first estimator is strongly consistent.